# A Leadership Vacuum: Please Step Up

Tags: discussion, moderation

For the last two months, I have been seeking an additional moderator for this site. Your community has grown and you need a new person to help assist the current moderation team in nurturing and monitoring your site! Unfortunately, I have had a bit of trouble finding this additional enthusiastic soul.

So, I am turning to the community and issuing a call to arms. **This community needs people to lead it!** Moderation is about accepting edits and handling flags, yes, but it's also about serving as a role model to the community. It's about helping shape the site, policy-wise and scope-wise, into something that can -- nay, will! -- be truly successful, valuable, and *makes the internet better!* The many things a moderator does are covered at greater length in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

This position  may seem like a tall order, but I am confident that there is someone who is dedicated to this site enough that he or she wants to take on the role. Furthermore, *you would not be going at it alone*. Moderators work as a *team* to address issues, move the site forward, and clarify the breadth of the site itself. It is a privilege (and a joy!) to be able to look at a community and know you've had a direct hand in building it.

I'll stress this much: this is a voluntary activity. If you opt to step in and then find yourself overwhelmed by Real Life or work or some such, you're free to leave or take a leave of absence, but you'd need to let the Community Managers and your fellow moderators know.

This site needs someone willing to stand up and say, "I want to make this place better!" If you're that person, *please say so!* We'd love to have you.

Comment: I'd be interested to help out. What do I do?

Comment: I nominate Peter as well. :)

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence, @datageist ! :-)

Comment: Hi @PeterK.! Just leave an answer to this post saying basically that -- that you're happy to step up and help out. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am interested to help out! I was involved in getting the proposal through Area 51, and I want to make the site as useful, interesting and welcoming as possible (within the bounds of the DSP.SE charter).